# custom-file-input webpack warning following Angular 13 upgrade

Tags: angular, webpack

I just recently updated a project to Angular 13 and am now seeing the following in dev during Live Reload.

```
[webpack-dev-server] Warnings while compiling.
localhost꞉4200/polyfills.js:1
[webpack-dev-server] WARNING
1 rules skipped due to selector errors:
  .custom-file-input:lang(en)~.custom-file-label -> unmatched pseudo-class :lang
```

This is reported in the terminal console and debug console when running `ng serve` or when the app recompiles respectively.

I did work out though that it seems to be triggered by the following code from bootstrap.css

```
.custom-file-input:lang(en) ~ .custom-file-label::after {
  content: "Browse";
}
```

That is from Bootstrap v4.6.1 release.

Not sure if this is related but my pollyfills.ts only has the following lines active:

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

I'm thinking I can safely ignore it for now as it's not my code but the bootstrap.css, just wanted to check any others have experienced it or thoughts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated the original thread with more information